# How to check whether url is working or not, through linux shell

Tags: linux, bash

How to check whether a particular url is woking or not, through linux shell? I tried through elinks, but it shows:

ERROR: This application requires javascript enabled in the browser

Comment: `curl -Is http://google.com | head -n 1`

Comment: It depends what you mean by 'working'. Do you mean if the server is up and responding with content? Or if the content itself is valid?

Answer (score 9):

You can do it easily using curl (you may have to install curl if you system doesn't already have it).

for example, performing

```
curl -is [URL YOU WANT TO CHECK] | head -n 1
```

will return you a [http status code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes). You can then determine the url exists or not from this status code. For example:

```
curl -is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21597851/how-to-check-whether-url-is-working-or-not-through-linux-shell | head -n 1
```

i.e, your question, will return a 200 status code. `HTTP/2 200`

But another url such as

```
curl -is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/madeupquestion/example | head -n 1
```

will return a 404, as it doesn't exist. `HTTP/2 404`

Comment: Please update the `http` to `https` to prevent Moved Permanently warnings.